# Inconvenient comment signature line break

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

Due to the length of my name, it's often wrapped in comments. This is entirely understandable. However, it often gets wrapped like this:

```
...[end of comment] -
Timothy Mueller-Harder
```

which looks really weird. I'm fine with

```
...[end of comment] -Timothy
Mueller-Harder
```

as well as

```
...[end of comment]
- Timothy Mueller-Harder
```

but wrapping between the hyphen and my first name is ridiculous. Please change this.

(Edit) Here's an example: [image]

Comment: Here is an example of such an erroneously signatured comment in action, if you still don't get it.

Comment: Looks okay to me here. Can you post a screenshot of a bad one? http://i.imgur.com/Zf7Ov.png

Comment: @NathanGreenstein Yes, it's showing up that way for me, now, as well. Unfortunately, the edit link is now remarkably unresponsive...

Comment: Here is a comment that causes my signature to wrap in the manner I just described.

Comment: So it appears that your proposed solution is, in fact, already implemented, and that most of our *browsers* are what's broken. Who knew?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rendered HTML is already like you're proposing, e.g.:

```
&ndash;&nbsp;<a href="/users/12285/timothy-mueller-harder"...
```

so this sounds like a browser issue.  Indeed, only Firefox seems to render the `&nbsp;` correctly*:

[image: Firefox ndash example]

<sup>* Unless we're doing something wrong, which is entirely possible :)</sup>

Comment: OK, thanks for your help. I probably should have looked at the HTML myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are advocating that Stack Exchange removes the space between the end of the comment and the username, or linebreaks the dash ending the comment, I am 100% opposed to that.

This is standard browser line-wrapping behavior. When content hits the end of a displayed line, it rewinds to the last (non-breaking) space, and then moves all the content onto the next line.

You're just going to keep running into this problem.

So what can you do? My only suggestion is to change your username. The only three names I could think of that could permanently resolve this issue would be `Timothy-Mueller-Harder`, `TMH`, or `TM-H`. You could abbreviate it in some other fashion, such as `Timothy M-H`, but that won't fix the issue. You will inevitably post a comment of some length that pushes not only `M-H` onto the next line, but `Timothy` as well.

Comment: I'm not. I'm advocating that they change it to a non-breaking space.